# Maximum Likelihood Estimator for Multivariate Bernoulli

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions, machine-learning

I am working on deriving Naive Bayes for document classification.

Each document is represented by a binary vector $x^i$ where $i=1,..,N$ for N documents. In this vector a cell is set to 1 if that cell representing a word is present at least once in the document, and left zero otherwise. Let's say there are 50,000 words hence each binary vector has 50,000 elements.

[image: multivar bernoulli for document words]

The joint distribution for Naive Bayes is

$p(x_1,...,x_{50000}) = \prod_{d=1}^{50000} p(x_d)=\prod_{d=1}^{50000} \alpha_d^{x_d}(1-\alpha_d)^{1-x_d}$

Likelihood is

$L(\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^N \prod_{d=1}^{50000} p(x_d^i) = \prod_{i=1}^N \prod_{d=1}^{50000} \alpha_d^{x_d^i}(1-\alpha_d)^{1-x_d^i}$

The text I am reading suggests maximum likelihood solution for $\alpha_d$ is $\alpha_d = \frac{N_d}{N}$, where  $N_d$ is the total of '1's for a dimension (word) across all documents, and N is the total number of documents. I am guessing this is obtained by taking derivative of the likelihood function, setting the result to zero, then solve for $\alpha_d$. One trick is I guess taking log of both sides, but even then, the algebra gets hairy pretty fast. Maybe I am missing something else. I would appreciate if someone could help with this derivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the loglikelihood

$$LL(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{50000}) = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{d=1}^{50000} {x_d^i}\log(\alpha_d)+(1-x_d^i)\log(1-\alpha_d) \; ,$$

it's pretty easy, you get the following equations to solve:

$$\sum_{i=1}^N\left(\frac{x_d^i}{\alpha_d}-\frac{1-x_d^i}{1-\alpha_d}\right) = 0$$

or after summing over $i$

$$\frac{N_d}{\alpha_d}-\frac{N-N_d}{1-\alpha_d} = 0 \; .$$

Comment: Hi, what happens to $\sum_{d=1}^{50000}$? Can it be dropped because we have zero on the RHS?

Comment: When you compute the partial derivatives of the loglikelihood function, you do it with respect to one $\alpha_d$, therefore all the terms which do not contain it are zero. Of course, there is one partial derivative for each $\alpha_d$ and thus just as many equations. But they all look the same. Solving one basically solves them all.

Comment: Can I ask what N is, and why in the nominator 1 is replaced by N?

Comment: I don't understand your question given the context. Read the question to which this is the answer.